# Android - What does adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated do?

Tags: android, dataadapter

What does the method adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated() accomplish?
There is no documentation on it.

I am trying to reload a ListView and notifyDataSetChanged or notifyDataSetInvalidated don't seem to accomplish anything.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It depends on the adapter implementation... if you take a look of the source code you will see that:

1. `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` calls the `notifyInvalidated()` of the `DataSetObservable` class ([see here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=es#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java&q=android%20notifyDataSetInvalidated&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc))
2. Then, `notifyInvalidated()` calls the `onInvalidated()` method for each `DataSetObserver` ([see here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=es#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/database/DataSetObservable.java&q=android%20DataSetObservable&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)).
3. Then comes the funny part: `onInvalidated()` [does not do anything](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=es#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/database/DataSetObserver.java&q=android%20DataSetObserver&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc)...

This is its implementation:

```
public void onInvalidated() {
    // Do nothing
}
```

`DataSetObserver` is an abstract class, so it's up to the subclass to decide what to do on `onInvalidated()`.

Comment: Note that you almost always want to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead of invalidated - changed will cause the adapter to redraw itself.

Answer (score 28):

As far as I know, the `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` method stops the adapter from accessing the data (in case it's invalid, unavailable, etc.). The `notifyDataSetChanged()` method updates the `ListView` so you can see the new data added, but you have to call it in the UI thread.

It helped me a lot to watch [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70) -- there are two sections where they mention those methods and explain how to use them correctly. Maybe it helps you too :)

Comment: Great video. Beeing more precised  look for 17:35 - http://youtu.be/wDBM6wVEO70?t=17m35s  , "the data is gone, we are not going to access it anymore" e.g the file was deleted. That nailed it for me.

Answer (score 20):

I recently ran into this question and wanted to elaborate for those who are wondering programmatically what is happening when you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and `notifyDataSetInvalidated()`. *Short answer, go [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView.AdapterDataSetObserver)

As @Cristian stated in his answer, when you call these notify methods on your Adapter it basically calls through a few classes and ends up calling `onChanged()`/`onInvalidated()` on the registered `DataSetObserver`s for your Adapter.

If you follow the code you will indeed see that [`DataSetObserver`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/database/DataSetObserver.java#DataSetObserver) is abstract as stated, and that the `onChanged()`/`onInvalidated()` methods are empty waiting for implementation by a subclass.

If this were the end of the story, then why do Android framework engineers keep telling us to call these methods if they do nothing? It took some digging but it turns out there is already a subclass of this `DataSetObserver` called [`AdapterDataSetObserver`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView.AdapterDataSetObserver) and it lives in the abstract class [`AdapterView`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/AdapterView.java#AdapterView) (which is extended by classes like `GridView` and `ListView`). This observer is automatically created by Android when you [`setAdapter()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/GridView.java#135) on your `AdapterView` and gets [registered](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/widget/BaseAdapter.java#37) to your Adapter.

It is here that you can see all the crazy stuff these methods actually do do. The documentation is poor and at first I thought I needed to register my own subclassed `DataSetObserver` to get these functioning, but turns out one is already created for you.

*Something I thought might be useful: I believe that you can register more than one `DataSetObserver` to your Adapter (in addition to the default one). This would allow you to do some extra work if needed (like maybe swap a progress bar view with an image view when bitmaps are done downloading).

Answer (score 3):

According to the "[**the world of listView**](http://lanyrd.com/2010/io2010/smwm/)" lecture, you should use it each time the listView has nothing to show (meaning empty data).

One example they talk about is when the filtering is done (on "publishResults" method). on the lecture video, it's on 36:00 .

The weird thing is, why didn't they just merge it with notifyDataSetChanged, which could check for the number of the items and decide to call it by itself...

According to what I've seen, what was talked on the lecture isn't quite right. if the adapter has shown some content before, and now it doesn't contain anything, and now you call notifyDataSetInvalidated, nothing will happen, so the content will remain, so I think it's safe to use notifyDataSetInvalidated only when the data doesn't change.

For example, if you handle the filtering, and you get the same results (and maybe it's enough to check the number of results) as before, you can call notifyDataSetInvalidated instead of notifyDataSetChanged

Comment: As your last paragraph, if you get the same results, you don't need to do anything, since the data is same as before :p

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono That's what I wrote. It's weird as I don't see the point of ever using this. I can't find a good scenario that it's useful.