# Fragment onCreateView() being called with old values

Tags: android, fragment

I have an Activity where I load fragments in a `FrameLayout` in the activity layout xml. I have 2 fragments: `ListFragment` and `PreferenceFragment`.

`ListFragment` uses an `ArrayAdapter` and displays an *array* which is a class variable and populated in the constructor of the ArrayAdapter. This contains dates which are stored in the database.

Now when the user clicks on preferences button in the ActionBar, the `ListFragment` is replaced by the `PreferenceFragment`. Here I allow the user to change the date format.

So far so good.

Now when the user presses **back** to go back from the `PreferenceFragment`, I override the `Activity.onBackPressed()` to replace the `PreferenceFragment` with the `ListFragment`.

Here I still see the dates with the old format, and the user's chosen setting is not reflected. Upon debugging, I saw that the `ListFragment.onCreateView()` is called **twice**. The first time it loads the newly loaded array with the new date format that the user just chose. The second time it loads the old date array (which somehow it saved!).

I am only using `FragmentTransaction.replace()` in the `Activity.onCreate()` and in the `Activity.onBackPressed()`.

I have spend the whole day to figure this out. As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201695/oncreateview-called-multiple-times-working-with-actionbar-and-fragments), this shouldn't be happening since I am using replace. I am unable to find anything online. Any suggestions are appreciated.

**UPDATE**: As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3669325/notifydatasetchanged-example/5092426#5092426), the `ArrayAdapter.onNotifyDatasetChanged()` only takes effect when the list is updated using the Arrayadpaters own add, clear ,etc methods. So now in the `ListFragment.onResume()` I call `adapter.clear()` and `adapter.addAll(sqliteclass.getArray())`. This works, but I am now making **2 trips** to the database, in `onCreate()` and `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no need to override `onBackPress()` to reverse a `FragmentTransaction`.
   Just call `addToBackStack()` on the `FragmentTransaction` replacing the list with the preferences.
2. Try calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ListAdapter` in `onResume()` of your `ListFragment`. This should force a recreate of the items' views.

Comment: This does not help. Somehow, the old format still gets displayed! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219779/android-what-does-adapter-notifydatasetinvalidated-do says that the `notifyDataSetInvalidated()` does not do anything..

Comment: sorry, `notifyDataSetChanged()` was what I wanted to suggest.

Comment: Still the same :(... Not sure whats wrong. Let me know if you anymore suggestions! Thanks for your time.